# JavaScript-HTML5 Login using Local storage,is safe?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I've created this Login system:

Username and is insert in a form on Login Page

Then

On submit,using websocket username and password (crypted) is send to a c# server application that control the data

Then

If the data are correct the username and other data except the password get saved on Local storage and used as session variables.

My question is: How this system is safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a security expert but I would recommend storing any sensitive data in cookie rather than local storage because cookies have extra measures of security that you can set such as

1. 'Secure' only allows https protocol.
2. 'HttpOnly' prevents Javascript from reading cookie so prevents from XSS attacks.

You can prevent CSRF attacks by setting CSRF tokens.

If you are building an application that requires authentication, there are many libraries out there you can integrate into your app which will most likely be more secure than building it yourself so I would advise you to look into those.